# Window object in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have seen in some documentation of PhantomJS that it can access the global "document" object but I don't know if it is also possible to access the global "window" object.

So my question is, is there a special way or I can just call the window object directly after I initialize a page using PhantomJS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running `phantomjs` from a terminal gives you an interactive session you can play around with.

If you then run `console.log(window)` you'll see you have access to the `window` object.

```
phantomjs> console.log(window);
[object DOMWindow]
```