# javascript callback closure undefined variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I just ran into something new today. I wanted to use phantomjs in node and was setting up phantom npm module [npm link](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node). The question lies in how you get "document.title". Please take a look at the example code they have on the site.

How did they get document injected into the callback function? Normally it would have been passed as a parameter in the callback, but somehow document is available without it being passed through the callback parameters.

Can someone explain how this is done? Also an explanation to why someone would do this and not just pass through the parameter?

```
var phantom;

phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(page) {
    return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
      console.log("opened google? ", status);
      return page.evaluate((function() {
        return document.title;
      }), function(result) {
        console.log('Page title is ' + result);
        return ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps as explained in this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437565/window-object-in-phatomjs), PhantomJS has a special feature where it puts (creates) the `window` and `document` objects in the global scope.

Generally this is done by assigning something to a variable without using the `var` keyword.

Example

```
var test = function(cb){
    document = 'test';
    cb();
}

test( function(){
    console.log(document);
});
```

Comment: so this would mean i can reference document anywhere else in my app after wards and document should be available?

Comment: Correct, once any running script defines `document` in the global scope, without the `var` keyword, any running future code can access that variable anywhere.

Comment: what would be the reason to put it into the global space instead of passing it as a param?

Comment: My buest guess as to why PhantomJS does this is to better mimic the environment of a real web browser, where `document` and `window` are always global variables, so it can work with existing scripts without needing modification.